# Is it possible that the spawn service rotates the 2D frame of turtlesim?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The blue screen where the turtles appear has of course four angles. Is it true that the origin is in the left bottom angle, right???? because when I use the spawn service it seems to me that the origin changes. It this possible????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300872/is-it-possible-that-the-spawn-service-rotates-the-2d-frame-of-turtlesim?/) by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved! in the spawn command the parameters are not the real positions but the pixel of the screen

---

Originally posted by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) with karma: 44 on 2018-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0